# Get DateTime Difference in a Array

Tags: datetime, c#-2.0

I need to Predict the date time differnce in a array of cells...

ex:

From Date:04/30/2011
To Date:05/30/2011

the array cell contains the dates from 04/30/2011 to 05/30/2011

Comment: What do you mean by "predict"? How does this prediction work?

Comment: if we use timespan we cud get the difference by date,by days,by hours...but it returns in a int value...but i need  intermediate dates between them in array[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
 DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime("04/30/2011");
            DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime("05/30/2011");
            List<DateTime> dateArray = new List<DateTime>();
            while (end > start.AddDays(1))
            {
               end= end.AddDays(-1);
               dateArray.Add(end);
            }
            DateTime[] array = dateArray.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **CalendarPeriodCollector** of [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx) library:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void CalendarPeriodCollectorSample()
{
  CalendarPeriodCollector collector =
     new CalendarPeriodCollector( new CalendarPeriodCollectorFilter(), 
     new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2011, 4, 30 ), new DateTime( 2011, 5, 30 ) ) );
  collector.CollectDays();
  foreach ( ITimePeriod period in collector.Periods )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Period: " + period ); // all days between 04/30/2011 and 05/30/2011
  }
} // CalendarPeriodCollectorSample
```

You can also specify exclusion days (holidays), or collect the periods by hours.